Does this behavior of std::string conform to the standard?
When I compile the following code with -std=c++26
#include <string>

class Foo {
public:
    constexpr static auto foo = std::string{"this_is_ok"};
    constexpr static auto bar = std::string{"a_very_long_string_that_probably_dont_fit_in_SSO"};
};

On Compiler Explorer
I got
<source>:6:27: error: constexpr variable 'bar' must be initialized by a constant expression
    6 |     constexpr static auto bar = std::string{"a_very_long_string_that_probably_dont_fit_in_SSO"};
      |                           ^     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:6:27: note: pointer to subobject of heap-allocated object is not a constant expression
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/15.0.0/../../../../include/c++/15.0.0/bits/allocator.h:193:31: note: heap allocation performed here
  193 |             return static_cast<_Tp*>(::operator new(__n));
      |            

Does this behavior of std::string conform to the standard?
I need a workaround to have some long std::string objects in constexpr.

You can't create constexpr std::string like this. Only transient creation is allowed. See Is it possible to use std::string in a constant expression?. Also How does constexpr std::string in C++20 work?

Can you use std::string_view instead?

See the answers in dupe, that mentions string_view. Also always do proper research before asking any question as recommended by the downvote button. One search for the error etc gives us many results/dupes.

" need a workaround to have some long std::string objects in constexpr...." No allowed except in very limited situation.

After using std::literals you can use the sv suffix to create std::string_view instances at compile-time: constexpr auto foo="always and ever ok, as long as no ICE"sv;
